# TypeError Exception in Marshal.dump

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using rails 3.2.12 and ruby 1.9.3.
In my application, i execute `Marshal.dump(self)` at first time, it's works fine. When the same line execute second time, it throws `TypeError Exception: Party can't be referred to` error message.
Both first and second time the value of self is `"object of party model"`. Please guide me why this error happens....